# Why do I get completely unexpected results after removing the where clause？

Tags: cnosdb

sql-1: select cpu, count(*) from cpu group by cpu;

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| cpu       | COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------+-----------------+
| cpu0      | 1               |
| cpu1      | 1               |
| cpu3      | 1               |
| cpu-total | 1               |
| cpu2      | 1               |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

sql-2: select cpu, count(*) from cpu where usage_user > 0.1 group by cpu;

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| cpu       | COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------+-----------------+
| cpu0      | 40225           |
| cpu-total | 30712           |
| cpu1      | 64182           |
| cpu3      | 51382           |
| cpu2      | 60444           |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

sql-3: select count(*) from cpu;

```
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 426880          |
+-----------------+
```

Is this a bug? Or is there a reason?
The cpu table is generated by telegraf grabbing the linux environment and writing. The table structure is as follows:

```
    +------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME      | DATA_TYPE             | COLUMN_TYPE | COMPRESSION_CODEC |
+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------+
| time             | TIMESTAMP(NANOSECOND) | TIME        | DEFAULT           |
| cpu              | STRING                | TAG         | DEFAULT           |
| host             | STRING                | TAG         | DEFAULT           |
| usage_guest      | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_guest_nice | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_idle       | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_iowait     | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_irq        | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_nice       | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_softirq    | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_steal      | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_system     | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
| usage_user       | DOUBLE                | FIELD       | DEFAULT           |
+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Can you also include results without the `group by`? Also; please don't share screenshots of your outputs, put the results in a code block.

Comment: What is the `cpu` table, you're querying, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement `SELECT COUNT(*)` may be sick. Use `count(time)` to get the correct:

```
d ❯ select count(*) from cpu;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 270             |
+-----------------+

d ❯ select cpu, count(time) from cpu group by cpu;
+-----------+-----------------+
| cpu       | COUNT(cpu.time) |
+-----------+-----------------+
| cpu2      | 45              |
| cpu3      | 45              |
| cpu1      | 45              |
| cpu4      | 45              |
| cpu0      | 45              |
| cpu-total | 45              |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Then when count(*), what does the value returned by cnosdb represent? Or is this just a simple bug?